# Chai fails on shallow equal assertion

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ethereum, chai

Chai should and does fail shallow equal assertion for regular JavaScript objects like [] or {}. However, it doesn't fail in case of some library's class object.

From documentation:

`.equal(val)` Asserts that the target is strictly (===) equal to the given val.

`.eql(obj)` Asserts that the target is deeply equal to the given obj.

```
const a = [];
const b = [];
console.log(a === b); // false - OK
expect(a).to.not.equal(b); // (===) pass - OK, these object have different references

const x = new utils.BigNumber('123456');
const y = new utils.BigNumber('123456');
console.log(x === y); // false - OK
expect(x).to.equal(y); // (====) pass - NOT OK, should fail
expect(x).to.eql(y); // (deep-eql) pass - OK
```

I would expect code to fail in `NOT OK` line. The BigNumber class comes from `ethers` library https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js

Comment: It fails on my machine: https://runkit.com/embed/b9269ebhiiri

Comment: Thx. So it turns out that i have `chai.use(somePlugin)` in other test file which modifies BNs behaviour in chai. Strangely enough chai does not unrelaod plugins...